# Powershell compare 2 arrays with different properties

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

i have 2 arrays. Both have a property for the file size, but the property name in the first array is "SizeInByte" and in the other array it is called "Length".
Is is possible to use compare-object to compare the two arrays based on the file size ?
So far i haven`t found a way to do this :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe one array to the Add-Member cmdlet and create a SizeInByte alias property for the Length property, then compare the two arrays by the same property name.

```
$LengthArr = $LengthArr | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name SizeInByte -Value Length -PassThru
Compare-Object $LengthArr $SizeInByteArr -Property SizeInByte
```